# Content not being removed from inside an element being overwritten

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

Simplest way to explain what is happening is by example:

Before:

```
<div id="top">
    <div>Row 1 - Horse</div>
    <div>Row 2 - Pony</div>
</div>
```

Now I call handlebars to overwrite $('#top') with:

```
<div>Row 1 - Cat</div>
```

After:

```
<div id="top">
    <div>Row 1 - Cat</div>
</div>
```

**BUT**
This is what it *looks* like:

```
Row 1 - Cat
Row 2 - Pony
```

Not until i manually highlight *Row 2 - Pony* or press CTRL+A does the text dissapear. It seems to be some sort of redraw problem within JS and I can't find anyeone else that has had this problem before.

**EDIT code sample**

**JS**

```
var source   = $("#top_html").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
$('#top').html(template({
    'load_top':'1',
    data_obj:return_obj
}));
```

**Handlebars**

```
{{#if load_top}}        
    {{#foreach data_obj}}
        <div>{{name}}</div>
    {{/foreach}}         
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Can you show us your (minimal) code ?

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers? That will help us determine whether it is a browser issue or a javascript issue. My guess would be a browser issue based on your description.

Comment: Only seems to happen in Chrome

Comment: Updating the browser to 24.0.1312.56m seemed to have fixed the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating Chrome to 24.0.1312.56m seemed to have fixed the problem.